# Is this javascript hack sufficient to mask a mailto link from bots?

Tags: javascript

```js
// contact link -- no peeking!
  $('.footer a.peek').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', atob('bWFpbHRvOmRvbnRzdGVhbEBtZS5jb20='));
  });
  $('.footer a.peek').focusout(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', '#');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="footer">
  <a class="peek" href="#">Contact Me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it will certainly reduce the number of bots, since most still don't run JS...

Answer (score 0):

That will probably mask the link from most bots, yes.

It will also mask the link from touchscreen devices (like smartphones) -- with no mouse cursor, they will never fire `mouseenter` events. This is probably undesirable. Consider other methods.

Comment: I updated the snippet, completely forgot about mobile thanks. using click event.